# Play framework use SOAP web services

Tags: scala, soap, playframework

I'm trying to implement SOAP web service client in Play Framework. I found `play-soap` lib but I cannot find repository:

https://github.com/playframework/play-soap

http://downloads.typesafe.com/rp/play-soap/SbtWsdl.html

When I add sbt plugin `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "play-soap-sbt" % "1.0")` it returns:

```
Error:Unresolved dependencies: com.typesafe.play#play-soap-sbt;1.0: not found
```

How can I implement SOAP webservices in Play Framework (Scala)?

Comment: Have you tried providing resolvers in build.sbt

Comment: Are you using Typesafe Reactive Platform?

Comment: I have such resolvers:
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

I created play framework project using `activator`

Comment: I use play framework 2.3.9 and Scala 2.11.4, does it matter?

Comment: I'm  having the same issue.

Comment: you need Lightbend Reactive Platform credentials to use play-soap-sbt plugin, since its a part of the Reactive Platform.

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](https://github.com/playframework/play-soap/blob/master/docs/SbtWsdl.md) and follow the install instructions. This is the open-sourced version of the plugin, and from the documentation it looks identical to the one in the official Play docs.

Essentially, add this to your project/plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("play-sbt-plugins", url("https://dl.bintray.com/playframework/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-soap" % "1.1.3")
```